# How can I have multiple views of the same file in MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop

MonoDevelop is supposed to have a split view since version [2.0](https://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/release-notes/monodevelop-2.0-released/) but I cannot find it. 
Some other posts say it's not in the menu but a [keyboard shortcut can be assigned to it](https://answers.unity.com/questions/449511/unity4-mono-develop-cant-find-split-view.html). However searching both split and unsplit show nothing in the search result. Comments later say it was buggy.

I'm using MonoDevelop 5.10 on Ubuntu.

Is this feature removed, because no one used it? Or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to View >> Editor columns >> Two columns. Yep, it should be called split view.

However, this is not valid in order to have multiple views of the same file. The only way I've found this to work is to open two MonoDevelop instances, make them open the same solution and file, and put them side by side.

Comment: But this doesn't allow me to have two instance open of the same file allowing me to have multiple views!

Comment: True. When you try to open a file that is already open, instead of opening it in the same notebook, creating a split view, it takes you to the notebook already open.

Comment: The only way I've found this to work is to open two MonoDevelop instances, make them open the same solution and file, and put them side by side.